# python - psutil.net_io_counters() access bytes sent

Tags: python

hi i am using psutil i want to have access to bytes_sent

```
net = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
```

output =>

```
{'lo': iostat(bytes_sent=122424, bytes_recv=122424, packets_sent=1408, packets_recv=1408, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0), 'kvnet': iostat(bytes_sent=3594694, bytes_recv=25226835, packets_sent=28971, packets_recv=29051, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0), 'eth0': iostat(bytes_sent=5591347, bytes_recv=29589927, packets_sent=33000, packets_recv=46178, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0)}
```

when i do this :

```
 sent = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent()
 receved = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv()
```

i get an error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)` returns a dict with all the interfaces statistics.

In order to get individual results you need to do something like:

```
net = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
# Notice no brackets in the end
sent = net['lo'].bytes_sent
received = net['lo'].bytes_recv

# or with the eth0 interface
sent = net['eth0'].bytes_sent
received = net['eth0'].bytes_recv
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the quotes:-

```
psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
```